# The sliding bar of my landing page html starts to fail when I change the name "Zetaceos" for the logo in png format

Tags: javascript, html, css

This happens when I see the mobile website or shrink the browser. Specifically, the pink eyelash is the one that hides quickly.[enter image description here][1]
[enter image description here][2]

The website is zetaceos.cl

```
<div class="banner">
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
            <div class="logo">
            <h1><a href="index.html">Zetaceos</a></h1>
                **<!--<h1><a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo_zetaceos_chico.png"</a></h1>-->
                    </div>
            <iframe style="position: absolute; bottom: 40px; right: 0px; left:105px;" src="https://open.spotify.com/embed?uri=spotify:artist:3472DBgO4lymN7orcUvBle" width="300" height="80" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
            <div class="top-nav">
                <span class="menu"> <img src="images/icon.png" alt=""/></span>
                <ul class="res">
                   <li><a href="index.html" class="active"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"> </span></a></li> 
                    <li><a href="sobre.html">Sobre la banda</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="disco.html">Reventó la ola</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="galeria.html">Galería</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="eventos.html">Eventos</a></li> 
                    <li class="nav-line"><a href="contacto.html">Contacto</a></li> 
               </ul>
```

By uncommenting the line of code in which the ** appear, the tab starts to fail

http://zetaceos.cl/sobre.html
http://zetaceos.cl/contacto.html

Comment: any solution?
thanks